# JavaFX TextField Get Clicked Item

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I'm trying to load(WebEngine) links that are in a TextArea when you click on them. But I have no idea how to get the clicked item.

This is something i tried:

```
area.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            WebController.getEngine().load((String) event.getSource());
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.getSource()` will be the `TextArea` in your case.

So your code would either be

```
area.setOnMouseClicked(event -> WebController.getEngine().load(((TextArea) event.getSource()).getText()));
```

or simpler:

```
area.setOnMouseClicked(event -> WebController.getEngine().load(area.getText()));
```

---

Edit - Simple `TextFlow` example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
    textFlow.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> {
        if(ev.getTarget() instanceof Text) {
            Text clicked = (Text) ev.getTarget();
            System.out.println(clicked);
        }
    });

    IntStream.range(0, 500).mapToObj(Integer::toString).map(Text::new).forEach(textFlow.getChildren()::add);

    BorderPane borderpane = new BorderPane(textFlow);
    borderpane.setPadding(new Insets(20));

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderpane, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Problem is my TextArea contains a lot of lines of text so that wouldn't work

Comment: Well in your question we do not see anything of that. If you need a particular text from an event, you should not put all of the text into one `TextArea`. You could use `TextFlow`, `ListView` or something else which allows to cherry pick single elements.

Comment: This is what im doing to add the text to a TextArea:HistoryClient.getHistory().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(s -> {
   area.appendText(s + "\n");
  }); How would i be able to add that to a TextFlow and if you click on it it would load it(getHistory() is an ArrayList containing the History you went to with the WebEngine)

Comment: See my edit, it is a simple example without any formatting etc, hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: That just displays numbers from 1 to 500 how would i display everything from my ArrayList?

Comment: Nvm got it already but a TextFlow doesn't got a scroll bar so yeah it looks really weird

Comment: It was an example, you can go on wrap it in a `ScrollPane` or use another component ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wanna see what it turned out here is my code im using:

```
package com.ekko.history;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import com.ekko.WebController;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

public class HistoryController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextFlow textFlow;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        textFlow.getChildren().clear();
        textFlow.setOnMouseClicked(ev -> {
            if(ev.getTarget() instanceof Text) {
                Text clicked = (Text) ev.getTarget();
                WebController.getEngine().load(clicked.getText());
            }
        });
        HistoryClient.getHistory().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(s -> {
            Text text = new Text(s + "\n");
            textFlow.getChildren().add(text);
        });
        HistoryClient.getHistory().clear();
    }
}
```

And this is the FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<ScrollPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ekko.history.HistoryController">
   <content>
      <TextFlow fx:id="textFlow" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Thanks to eckig for helping me!